# Combine json files containing COCO person keypoint annotations

Tags: python, json, labeling

I've annotated some images using the [coco-annotator](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator).
I'd like to combine these annotations with the existing one ("person_keypoints_train2017.json" and "person_keypoints_val2017.json").

Has anyone ever managed to do so?
If yes, how? (preferrably using python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

json vlaues can be accessed using the json module try reading both the files and hence decide what values to combine:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
filename1 = "person_keypoints_train2017.json"
with open(filename1) as f:
    data_filename1 = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
filename2 = "person_keypoints_val2017.json"
with open(filename1) as f:
    data_filename2 = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

now you have two dictionaries, you can manipulate data.
In order to save them to the file:

```
    with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Comment: That sounds good. There seem to be 2 small issues: 1) "image_id" might be doubly assigned as they are randomly generated hash codes. 2) the `json.dump` command doesn't print the respective supercategories. 
The first problem has probably to be fixed manually. The second should be part of the `json.dump` command

Comment: It's not a complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Simple solution:

Use the following tool [Merge COCO Files](https://github.com/mohamadmansourX/Merge_COCO_FILES)

***You Don't Need to install any Library***

Simply git clone and run the following:

```
python merge.py Input1.json Input2.json OUTPUT_JSON.json
```

---

## From Scratch Solution:

To combine them you need to follow these steps:

1. Get the whole images from all the annotation files and store them in dict with their IDs (e.g. each image should be represented as a tuple (filename, ImageID) where ImageID is used to map to annotations)
2. Check if there's a duplicate image name (So that we don't have duplicate annotations)
3. Merge Images lists from different annotation files into one list
4. Reset ImageID's and keep a temp dict for mapping old to new.
5. Gather the annotations from the files and themn use the old_to_new mapping to map them to the new image's IDS.
6. Reset Annotations IDs