# I want to fetch the data in data.json using this query or code

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am using VS code + git bash to scrape this data into JSON. But I am not getting any data into JSON or I did not get anything in JSON. JSON file is empty.

```
import scrapy

class ContactsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'contacts'

    start_urls = [
        'https://app.cartinsight.io/sellers/all/amazon/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for contacts in response.xpath("//td[@title= 'Show Contact']"):
            yield{
                'show_contacts_td': contacts.xpath(".//td[@id='show_contacts_td']").extract_first()
                }
            next_page= response.xpath("//li[@class = 'stores-desc hidden-xs']").extract_first()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page_link= response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Did you try the json module from python? I guess it will be quite helpful to you.

Comment: I will try and let you know if doesn't work! Thank you man!

Comment: Try reading this answer of mine [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095457/combine-json-files-containing-coco-person-keypoint-annotations/58097801#58097801) this will help you read and write data to the json file

Answer (score 1):

The URL `https://app.cartinsight.io/sellers/all/amazon/` you want to scrape is redirecting to this URL `https://app.cartinsight.io/`. The second URL didn't contain this XPath `"//td[@title= 'Show Contact']"` which results in skipping the `for` loop in `parse` method and thus you are not getting your desired results.